# Set/Get style height in javascript

Tags: javascript

I try

```
console.log(document.getElementById('content').style.height);
```

prints nothing, just an empty line in console.

```
console.log(document.getElementById('content').clientHeight);
```

prints the height.

```
document.getElementById('content').style.height = '50px';
```

has no effect. I am in lastest chrome browser. I want to be able to read and set height, however set does not work. I want to use vanilla js. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide the relevant html, so that someone can help you.

Comment: @AkhilSekharan it's a div element with id=content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/YTmNz/

JS:

```
function ChangeHeight(){
        var e1 = document.getElementById("content");
        e1.style.height = "400px";
    }
setTimeout(ChangeHeight, 2000);
```

Unfortunately you cannot retrieve height with `.style.height`unless you have already set that property before.

 You can use jQuery to retrieve `.height()`

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but depending on what element `content` is you may also need to add `display:block;` to allow it to be given a height.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

document.getElementById('content').offsetHeight

document.getElementById('content').offsetWidth

it will give the height/width of element;